# Spark Structured Streaming cannot read from kafka inside docker

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Cannot fix issue after submitting spark structured streaming job for reading from kafka.
Code example of spark job:

```
object KafkaStructuredStreaming {


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName(getClass.getName)
      .master("spark://spark-master:7077")
      .getOrCreate()

    val df = spark
      .readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka:9092")
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
      .option("subscribe", "tweet-upload-6")
      .option("enable.auto.commit", false)
      .option("group.id", "Structured-Streaming-Examples")
      .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
      .load()

    df.printSchema()

    val consoleOutput = df.writeStream
      .outputMode("append")
      .format("console")
      .start()
    consoleOutput.awaitTermination()

  }
}
```

One note: Kafka and spark nodes are in the same docker network, everything worked before with spark-streaming but i switched to structured streaming because i had issue with single input stream -> multiple output streams.

I am getting now error:

```
07721793-driver-0] Error connecting to node kafka:9092 (id: 1001 rack: null)
submit-spark-job  | java.net.UnknownHostException: kafka
submit-spark-job  |     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1282)
submit-spark-job  |     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1194)
submit-spark-job  |     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1128)
submit-spark-job  |     at org.apache.kafka.clients.DefaultHostResolver.resolve(DefaultHostResolver.java:27)
submit-spark-job  |     at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.resolve(ClientUtils.java:111)
submit-spark-job  |     at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:512)
submit-spark-job  |     at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates$NodeConnectionState.access$200(ClusterConnectionStates.java:466)
submit-spark-job  |     at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates.currentAddress(ClusterConnectionStates.java:172)
submit-spark-job  |     at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:985)
submit-spark-job  |     at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:311)
submit-spark-job  |     at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.trySend(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:498)
submit-spark-job  |     at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:255)
submit-spark-job  |     at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.pollNoWakeup(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:306)
submit-spark-job  |     at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$HeartbeatThread.run(AbstractCoordinator.java:1367)
submit-spark-job  | 21/10/18 22:44:41 WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-4d4a80ae-01a7-4679-8393-42aaa0e35e6a-307721793-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-4d4a80ae-01a7-4679-8393-42aaa0e35e6a-307721793-driver-0] Error connecting to node kafka:9092 (id: 1001 rack: null)
submit-spark-job  | java.net.UnknownHostException: kafka
```

also

```
85949862d6d3-1705030665-driver-0] Group coordinator kafka:9092 (id: 2147482646 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid due to cause: null.isDisconnected: true. Rediscovery will be attempted.
submit-spark-job  | 21/10/18 23:03:46 WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-aafbb352-744d-438a-bd45-85949862d6d3-1705030665-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-aafbb352-744d-438a-bd45-85949862d6d3-1705030665-driver-0] Connection to node 1001 (kafka/172.18.0.4:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
submit-spark-job  | 21/10/18 23:03:47 WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-aafbb352-744d-438a-bd45-85949862d6d3-1705030665-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-aafbb352-744d-438a-bd45-85949862d6d3-1705030665-driver-0] Connection to node 1001 (kafka/172.18.0.4:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
submit-spark-job  | 21/10/18 23:03:47 WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-aafbb352-744d-438a-bd45-85949862d6d3-1705030665-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-aafbb352-744d-438a-bd45-85949862d6d3-1705030665-driver-0] Connection to node 1001 (kafka/172.18.0.4:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
submit-spark-job  | 21/10/18 23:03:48 WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-aafbb352-744d-438a-bd45-85949862d6d3-1705030665-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-aafbb352-744d-438a-bd45-85949862d6d3-1705030665-driver-0] Connection to node 1001 (kafka/172.18.0.4:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
submit-spark-job  | 21/10/18 23:03:48 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (172.18.0.7 executor 0): org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
submit-spark-job  |     at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:823)
submit-spark-job  |     at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:665)
submit-spark-job  |     at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:613)
submit-spark-job  |     at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.InternalKafkaConsumer.createConsumer(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:124)
submit-spark-job  |     at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.InternalKafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:61)
submit-spark-job  |     at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.InternalKafkaConsumerPool$ObjectFactory.create(InternalKafkaConsumerPool.scala:206)
submit-spark-job  |     at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.InternalKafkaConsumerPool$ObjectFactory.create(InternalKafkaConsumerPool.scala:201)
submit-spark-job  |     at org.apache.commons.pool2.BaseKeyedPooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BaseKeyedPooledObjectFactor
```

Docker compose files:

```
version: '2'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"

  kafka:
    image: linuxkitpoc/kafka:latest
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: "9092"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  tweet-producer:
    image: mkovacevic/tweet-producer-app:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - kafka
```

(created in default network : twitter-streaming_default)
and

```
version: '3'
services:
  spark-master:
    image: bde2020/spark-master:3.1.1-hadoop3.2
    container_name: spark-master
    hostname:  spark-master
    ports:
      - "7077:7077"
    environment:
      - INIT_DAEMON_STEP=setup_spark
  spark-worker-1:
    image: bde2020/spark-worker:3.1.1-hadoop3.2
    container_name: spark-worker-1
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - "SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077"
  spark-worker-2:
    image: bde2020/spark-worker:3.1.1-hadoop3.2
    container_name: spark-worker-2
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    ports:
      - "8082:8081"
    environment:
      - "SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077"
  submit-spark:
    image: mkovacevic/spark-streaming-app:latest
    container_name: submit-spark-job
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
      - spark-worker-1
      - spark-worker-2

networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: twitter-streaming_default
```

Any suggestions??

Comment: Well first of all show us your `/etc/hosts` or whatever is the equivalent of it on windows. Try pinging `kafka:9092`. It seems like host name `kafka` is not resolved properly. Also, post your docker files so we can see the network setup. It had to say anything without that.

Comment: Content of etc/hosts on spark-submit-job container ```127.0.0.1-    1 localhostroot           450 May  3  2019 krb5.conf
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.18.0.9      cec68fa15dfa```  Also i am able to ping kafka from all spark containers, docker compose files for spark and kafka uploaded to question description.

Answer (score 0):

Each compose file creates its own, isolated default bridge network.

If you want to use two files, then you explicitly have to add the network to every service. Otherwise, you need to put all services in the one file

By the way, `linuxkitpoc/kafka` image hasn't been updated in years. I suggest you use something else for Kafka. Personal recommendation would be ones from Bitnami

Comment: Looks like Bitnami image helped! @OneCricketeer thanks!